# npm publish is renaming .gitignore to .npmignore

Tags: npm, yeoman, yeoman-generator, npm-publish

I've created a Yeoman generator to create a basic Git repository folder structure. One of the assets is a `.gitignore` file. This is in the `\generators\app\templates\` folder.

When I publish this generator to my NPM registry, the `.gitignore` file is renamed to `.npmignore` and then the generator fails as it's trying to copy a file that no longer exists.

How can I stop this happening?

Answer (score 1):

What we ended up doing is renaming the .gitignore files to dot-gitignore and renaming them after the generation :
in index.js :

```
  // called at the end by yeoman
    end() {
    
                extfs.copyFileSync('_gitignore','.gitignore);
                extfs.unlinkSync('_gitignore');
    }
```